# sql server ML service gives low memory error for large data (Association Rule Mining Project)

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2019, mlxtend, sql-server-ml-services

I have a project that I want to find the rules of correlation between goods in the shopping cart .to do this ,I use the ML service(Python) in Sql Server ,and I use the `mlxtend` library to find the association rule.but the problem I have is that the `fpgrowth` function apparently uses a lot of memory, to the point where it stops working and gives errors.as far as possible, do the data preprocessing with sql server to be more efficient.

Part of the code :

```sql
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Me 
-- Create date: 2021-01-01
-- Description: Association Rule 
-- =============================================
--pip install mlxtend==0.16.0 --no-cache-dir
CREATE      PROCEDURE [Shopping].[CalculateAssociationRule] 
    @CompanyID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @confidence DECIMAL(7,6) =0.5 --DEFAULT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Declare Variable
    DECLARE @input_query NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'SELECT Int_DocShoppingID [TID],Int_StuffID [SID] FROM ##DocDetails' 
    DECLARE @Pattern VARCHAR(150)=N'[0-9]+\.?[0-9,.]*'

-- Declare Python Code
DECLARE @pyScript NVARCHAR(max)='
# import lib
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori,fpgrowth
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

#Change Data Shape to TranEncoder
#dataset=[data.SID.tolist() for id, data in data.groupby("TID")]
l=data[''list''].tolist()
del data
dataset=[i.split('','') for i in l]
del l
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
del dataset
#Run Association Rule (FPG) Algorithm
Result =pd.DataFrame(columns=[''antecedents'',''consequents'',''antecedent support'',''consequent support'',''support'',''confidence'',''lift'' ,''leverage'',''conviction''])
frequent_itemsets = fpgrowth(df, min_support=0.02, use_colnames=True)
if frequent_itemsets.empty == False:
    Result=association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold='+CAST(@confidence AS VARCHAR(max))+')
del frequent_itemsets
Result[''antecedents'']= Result[''antecedents''].astype(str)
Result[''consequents'']= Result[''consequents''].astype(str)
#Result Output
OutputDataSet=Result
'
    EXECUTE sys.sp_execute_external_script 
     @language = N'python37' 
    ,@script = @pyScript 
    ,@input_data_1 = @input_query 
    ,@input_data_1_name = N'data' 
--WITH result sets (([antecedents] VARCHAR(max),[consequents] VARCHAR(max),[antecedent support] VARCHAR(max),[consequent support] VARCHAR(max),[support] VARCHAR(max),[confidence] VARCHAR(max),[lift] VARCHAR(max),[leverage] VARCHAR(max),[conviction] VARCHAR(max)));

END
```

Python Code :

```py
# import lib
import pandas as pd
from mlxtend.preprocessing import TransactionEncoder
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import apriori,fpgrowth
from mlxtend.frequent_patterns import association_rules

#Change Data Shape to TranEncoder
#dataset=[data.SID.tolist() for id, data in data.groupby("TID")]
l=data['list'].tolist()
del data
dataset=[i.split(',') for i in l]
del l
te = TransactionEncoder()
te_ary = te.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
df = pd.DataFrame(te_ary, columns=te.columns_)
del dataset
#Run Association Rule (FPG) Algorithm
Result =pd.DataFrame(columns=['antecedents','consequents','antecedent support','consequent support','support','confidence','lift' ,'leverage','conviction'])
frequent_itemsets = fpgrowth(df, min_support=0.02, use_colnames=True)
if frequent_itemsets.empty == False:
    Result=association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric="confidence", min_threshold=0.5)
del frequent_itemsets
Result['antecedents']= Result['antecedents'].astype(str)
Result['consequents']= Result['consequents'].astype(str)
#Result Output
OutputDataSet=Result
```

Error : MemoryError

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 3
A 'python37' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
STDOUT message(s) from external script: 
2021-12-08 10:49:22.38  Error: Python error: <class 'MemoryError'>:   File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\fpgrowth.py", line 72, in fpgrowth

  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mlxtend\frequent_patterns\fpcommon.py", line 38, in generate_itemsets
```

Tools used in the project :

```
1. Sql Sever 2019-CU14
2.Python 3.7.9 (External Language in sql server)
3.Python Lib And Version
Package         Version
--------------- -------
cycler          0.11.0
fonttools       4.28.3
joblib          1.1.0
kiwisolver      1.3.2
matplotlib      3.5.0
mlxtend         0.17.0
numpy           1.21.4
packaging       21.3
pandas          1.3.4
Pillow          8.4.0
pip             21.3.1
pyodbc          4.0.32
pyparsing       3.0.6
python-dateutil 2.8.2
pytz            2021.3
scikit-learn    1.0.1
scipy           1.7.3
setuptools      47.1.0
setuptools-scm  6.3.2
six             1.16.0
threadpoolctl   3.0.0
tomli           1.2.2
------------------------
4. 16GB Ram & Cpu core 12
```

*Is there a solution to do this more efficiently and avoid errors?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prevent low memory error `Resource governor` can be enabled

```sql
ALTER EXTERNAL RESOURCE POOL [default] WITH (max_memory_percent=94, AFFINITY CPU = AUTO)
GO
ALTER RESOURCE GOVERNOR RECONFIGURE;

GO
```